# C++ cin prints the variable without me telling it to do that

Tags: c++, input, cin, cout

## Introduction

I am trying to code a converter for bin/oct/dec/hex numbers in c++. At first I print a message in a console asking the user to insert the type of conversion he wants to do and, followed by the `cin` that allows him to enter the conversion and then i ask him for the number followed by the `cin` that allows him to enter the number.

## My problem

My problem is that after the user inserts the conversion, the variable gets printed on the console without me telling it that.

## What I've Tried

I looked on the docs and in their example they do it like this:

```
cout << "Please enter an integer value: ";
cin >> i;
cout << "The value you entered is " << i;
cout << " and its double is " << i*2 << ".\n";
```

And that is similar to my code(which you will see below). 
I also tried to do `getline(cin, type)` but still the variables would get printed without me coding that.

## My code

**Faulty code:**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  string type;
  int n;
  cout << "Insert what type of conversion you want to make(binoct, bindec, binhex, octbin, octdec, octhex, decbin, decoct, dechex, hexbin, hexoct, hexdec): ";
  cin >> type;
  cout << "Insert the number you want to convert: ";
  cin >> n;
  return 0;
}
```

**Input**

```
binoct
1001
```

**Output**

```
 Insert what type of conversion you want to make(binoct, bindec, binhex,octbin, octdec, octhex, decbin, decoct, dechex,hexbin, hexoct, hexdec):binoct
 binoct
 Insert the number you want to convert:1001
 1001
```

**Expected output:**

```
Insert what type of conversion you want to make(binoct, bindec, binhex,octbin, octdec, octhex, decbin, decoct, dechex,hexbin, hexoct, hexdec):binoct
Insert the number you want to convert:1001
```

## Additional notes

I should mention that before this version of the code I did use `cout` to print my variables to see if it works but i re-built the code a few times and now there's no `cout << type` or `cout << n` inside my code 
I looked on stackoverflow and I didn't seem to see anything similar, if this is a duplicate I apologize.

Comment: Try to clean/rebuild your project. Your code is ok.

Comment: Please post a [mcve].

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. This includes a buildable program, its input, expected output, and actual output, verbatim.

Comment: By 'print my variable's do you mean the terminal showing the characters as you type them?

Comment: after I press enter the string/number I written gets printed on the screen, I will update the code with w mcv example and the output

Comment: looks like that you are confused since in console you see what you have typed as input and what is printed to output by your program. Basically you see problem where there is no problem.

Comment: Plus 1 for the nice presentation of the question :)

Comment: An excellent presentation, but tge claim is not reproducible https://ideone.com/QIgEwr

Comment: it is not reproducible indeed because i needed to clean and rebuild my code, I tested it on an online ide too a few minutes ago and it worked as intended

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code is fine, either clean and rebuild your project, or it has something to do with your project / debug settings, that print out the value.

Try Building and Running the Program in release mode.